# Cakephp Bakery Stopped working

Tags: php, cakephp

I was using cakephp bakery 2.x version and suddenly it stopped working,
I am using windows 10 , 64bit version.

[image]

I swear I didnt touch the database file, I was modifying bakery to work with bootstrap. I can't see to root out the problems.

[image]

This is what i as working on last time it stopped.

Comment: you need to configure database in database.php

Comment: Run the shell from within the `app` directory, not from within the `app\Console` directory.

Answer (score 0):

configure database.php using your database username and password its not getting any valid database configuration. Wish it helps

Comment: it is correct ,but the path seem to shift somehow. Should be app/config/database.php

Comment: database is correct and app is running , just bakery /

Comment: Your version of PHP is 5.2.8 or higher.

Your tmp directory is writable.

The FileEngine is being used for core caching. To change the config edit APP/Config/core.php

Your database configuration file is present.

CakePHP is able to connect to the database.

Comment: Yes its true. have you given your database username and password in database.php? Have you also checked settings page is it showed your database configuration is ok?

Comment: >> Your database configuration file is present. CakePHP is able to connect to the database <<< this is from checked setting page

Comment: yes that means you need to give acess of database to cakephp then it can connect, either how it got the database you want to use. configuration file means you need to configure that file.

Comment: this is my settings. -----> public $default = array(
  'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
  'persistent' => false,
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'login' => 'root',
  'password' => '',
  'database' => 'digital_store_db',
  'prefix' => '',
  //'encoding' => 'utf8',
 );

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142329/discussion-between-asif-uddin-and-wayne-tun).